# ERROR 1824 (HY000): Failed to open the referenced table

Tags: mysql

Get this error trying to define tables in MySQL. Here is the SQL:

```
create table user (
 id integer not null auto_increment,
 first_name varchar(50) not null,
 last_name varchar(50) not null,
 type enum('admin', 'manager', 'employee') not null,
 password varchar(60) not null,
 email varchar(80) not null,
 phone varchar(30),
 enabled boolean not null,
 primary key(id),
 unique key(email)
);

create table manual_time(
 user integer not null,
 type enum('Misc', 'paid time off', 'training') not null,
 work_date date not null,
 start_time time not null,
 end_time time not null,
 edit_at datetime not null,
 edit_by integer not null,
 index(user, work_date),
 constraint foreign key(edit_by) references user(id),
 constraint foreign key(user) references user(id)
);
```

ERROR 1824 (HY000): Failed to open the referenced table 'user'

My default engine is InnoDB.

Comment: Your query seems fine. But you can try renaming the `user` table to `users`.

Comment: `user` is a MySQL keyword, that may be interfering. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

I was restoring the database from a dump from another server.  When I looked at the dump code, it actually had ENGINE=MYISAM in the table definition, even though I never specified that. Once I added that to my new table definition, it worked.

Answer (score -2):

try use select * from dbname.tablename;